# Discrete Uniform distribution random number

Tags: random

I tried to generate discrete Uniform random number with (a+(b-a)*R) where R is random sample which is generated by liner Congruential method. But still I have doubt in the creation of D uniform number. Please give me anyone perfect formula for discrete uniform random number?

Answer (score 0):

A linear generator is not a true random number generator. If you want a true random generator you need a good source of entropy. In Windows there are a number of interfaces to access entropy collected by the system. In Linux there is /dev/random. Better still would be a hardware source like the new intel DRNG instruction.

Once you have a good source, the source should be conditioned (unless conditioning is already applied). A simple way to do this is to seed a stream cipher such as AES in CTR mode. In fact AES/CTR is an excellent psuedo random generator if you use a random key as the seed.

Comment: I believe the question is not about generating "truly random numbers".  In fact the question is vague as it is.